# How to upload more than 1 file at a time using Apache Commons FileUpload?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I am trying to write a servlet using Apache Commons FileUpload. I am just wondering how to organize multiple file uploads if two users would use the same upload servlet?

Comment: To learn more about servlets and threading, I suggest to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with that - just don't use instance variables of the servlet. Use only local variables.

Comment: @user592704 - if you don't have instance variables of the servlet you won't have multithreading problems.

Comment: but the method I am going to use with the doPost is very long because it reads and writes client file... So the synch way may stuck all next requests for long time :( What should be done in that case?

Comment: Don't use synchronized doX methods

Comment: You mean I have to put all the code to doPut method only and that will help?

Comment: No I don't use synchronized doX methods but I tried invoke the  synchronized method (upload method) with doPost method... Correct me please

Comment: @user592704 don't use any synchronized methods, and don't use any instance variables.

Comment: What you mean saying "don't use any instance variables"? You mean I cannot do things like File file=new File("") ?

Comment: @user592704 this is local variable. instance variables are those defined at class level.

Comment: Oh, I used to know it as a "field" :)
OK, so you mean all the read/write will be just for each one session so no need to use synchronized then?